# Why is an argument of onChange nested in <p>...</p> in Gutenberg custom block RichText?

Tags: block-editor

When editing a `RichText` on an admin panel, `onChange`'s argument is nested in a paragraph tag like `<p>my input</p>`. However, I have not specified `p` tag anywhere in my source code. Even when I try specifying `tagName='h2'` for an attribute and a RichText, onChange still gets `<h2><p>my input</p></h2>`. I can't remove

. I have no idea how to fix. Can anybody know what's going on?

Also, an editing page is styled with my custom css, but a public page isn't. It might have something to do.

Thank you in advance!

```js
var el = window.wp.element.createElement;
var RichText = window.wp.blockEditor.RichText;

wp.blocks.registerBlockType( 
  'myblock/title',
  {
    title: 'title',
    icon: 'heading',
    category: 'text',
    example: {},
    attributes: {
      text: {
        type: 'string',
        default: '',
      },
    },
    edit: function (props) {
      var blockProps = wp.blockEditor.useBlockProps();
      console.log(props)
      return el(
        RichText, Object.assign(blockProps, {
          onChange: function handleChange(text) {
            console.log(text)
            props.setAttributes({text: text})
          },
          value: props.attributes.text,
          placeholder: 'Input title',
          multiline: true,
          className: props.className,
        })
      );
    },
    save: function (props) {
      var blockProps = wp.blockEditor.useBlockProps.save();
      return el(
        RichText.Content,
        Object.assign(blockProps, {
          value: props.attributes.text,
        })
      );
    },
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have `multiline: true`, [as documented](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/rich-text/README.md):

> By default, a line break will be inserted on `Enter`. If the editable
> field can contain multiple paragraphs, this property can be set to
> create new paragraphs on `Enter`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my time. When I use default Heading tag, it works just like `multiline: true` and it doesn't have inner `<p>` tag. Do you know how I can modify my RichText to work like it?

Comment: @Watanabe.N [The heading doesn't use `multiline:true`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/heading/edit.js), maybe you can get more info from the source code of the block directly?